# Svelte component not re-rendering with new values if text input is inside an each loop

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-store

I have an editor that contains inputs inside `each` loop. When text inside input is changed the writable store is updated, but in another component where I loop over the values from store re-render is not triggered.

```
<script>
    import { writable } from "svelte/store";
    const invoiceItems = writable([
         {
             id: 0,
             text: "Test",
        }
    ]);
</script>
<input 
    type="text" 
    bind:value={$invoiceItems[0].text} 
    on:keyup={() => {console.log($invoiceItems[0].text);}} 
/>
{#each $invoiceItems as item, index (item.id)}
    <input 
        type="text" 
        bind:value={item.text} 
        on:keyup={() => {console.log($invoiceItems[0].text);}} 
    />
{/each}
{#each $invoiceItems as { id, text }}
    <div>{id}{text}</div>
{/each}
<div>
    {$invoiceItems[0].text}
</div>
```

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/0fa5f5cd1ee247afbbdc9a77266fb4f8?version=3.9.1

The above REPL shows the problem live - typing in the second input does not update texts, while outside of the loop it works fine. How can I get this to re-render properly?

Comment: Looks like a bug — I've raised an issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3455

Comment: @RichHarris the solution we find working is this https://svelte.dev/repl/5db41a94277a43ea8ca3052549e40746?version=3.9.1 but this feels a bit weird - I would expect the loop to work normally.

Comment: This issue is now fixed.

Comment: I still face this , issue am updating <text> inside svg, upon width change, its not rerendered but the same thing in html is working.